# Check if a <li> contain <a> with a certain class

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have this and I want to check the first `<li>` who contains `<a>` with the class `.selected`.

I have tried this : `$( "li a" ).first().hasClass('selected')` but my `<li>` isn't detected.

Here is my HTML code.

```
<ul>
  <li>
    <a class="thumbnail selected">
     <img src="thumb1.jpg">
    </a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a class="thumbnail unselect">
     <img src="thumb2.jpg">
    </a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a class="thumbnail unselect">
     <img src="thumb3.jpg">
    </a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a class="thumbnail unselect">
     <img src="thumb4.jpg">
    </a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a class="thumbnail unselect">
     <img src="thumb5.jpg">
    </a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Could you help me ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use .has() like

```js
$('li:has(a.selected)').first().addClass('found')
```

```css
.found {
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li>
    <a class="thumbnail selected">
      <img src="thumb1.jpg">
    </a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a class="thumbnail unselect">
      <img src="thumb2.jpg">
    </a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a class="thumbnail unselect">
      <img src="thumb3.jpg">
    </a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a class="thumbnail unselect">
      <img src="thumb4.jpg">
    </a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a class="thumbnail unselect">
      <img src="thumb5.jpg">
    </a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: There is a problem i'm checking `if( $( 'li:has(a.selected)' ).first() ){` and the test is always true.

Comment: @John what is it you really want to check?

Comment: @John are you trying to check whether the first `li` has `a.selected` element inside it? if so then `if($('li:first').has('a.selected').length)` or `if($('li:first').is(':has(a.selected)'))`

Comment: Yes, if I'm on the first `li`and if this `li` contains `a` with the .selected class I want to do something.

Comment: @John what do you mean by `I'm on the first li`?

Comment: The first element in `<ul>`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/98677/discussion-between-arun-p-johny-and-john).

Answer (score 0):

For the first Selected anchor tag simply try this

```
$('li a.selected:first')
```

Comment: He needs the <li>, not the <a>